# OneSignal with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, onesignal

My site is based on angular 2 and I want to show notification to user in the panel. So I used OneSignal for this purpose but there is a problem with it. when I added the OneSignal script the page content wont load and browser shows the blank page and when I remove the script of OneSignal everything is fine.

the load script which cause the problem :

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async='async'></script>
```

and the initialization of OneSignal inside component :

```
    ngOnInit(){
    var OneSignal = window['OneSignal'] || [];
    OneSignal.push(["init", {
        appId: "xxx-xxx-xxx",
        autoRegister: false, 
        subdomainName: 'https://something.onesignal.com',   
        httpPermissionRequest: {
            enable: true
        },
        notifyButton: {
            enable: true 
        }
    }]);

}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in browsers console?

Comment: No there is nothing in console

Comment: make it `let OneSignal = window['OneSignal'] || [];`

Comment: this is not the problem, the problem is with the source script not the implementation and I don't think change var to let is a very good solution

Comment: `Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.`Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)

Comment: try removing async='async' from script tag and re-run again

Comment: @Kermani I think your answer isn't related to this topic

Comment: thanks to @yurzui the problem has been solved

Comment: @hosseinahmadi yeah, I think so

Comment: Hey @yurzui, thank you very much for figuring out the issue. Can I ask how you were able to see the warning? I wasn't able to see any warning or error outputs on other sites with this issue. We'll be fixing this issue soon @ https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/issues/199.

Comment: @Jason Seems es6 polyfill use try catch so we can't see this issue. Scripts order is very important for zonejs. If we use async attribute then we can not be sure that OneSignal loaded before zonejs. To see this problem i've created plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/lpal29dghPPl78yo4yur?p=preview See also my answer to this question

Answer (score 3):

You need to load `OneSignalSDK` script before `zonejs` otherwise see picture below

https://plnkr.co/edit/lpal29dghPPl78yo4yur?p=preview
[image]

Comment: So the solution was to add the script in the HTML and that's it, right? Is there another way to accomplish this on more recent version of Angular?